# static variable in function call doesn't get updated

Tags: visual-c++

This code doesn't work for obvious reasons. The first time the function is called it works. But the second time on not working with serial_number_a and static functionality. How do get the static variable to get updated?

```
void Dialog5::GetSerialNumber(LPWSTR& lpSerialNumber, LPSTR& SerialNumber)
{
  static CString serial_number;
  m_SerialNumber.GetWindowTextW(serial_number);
  static CStringA serial_number_a(serial_number);
  lpSerialNumber = serial_number.GetBuffer(0); //Adress
  SerialNumber = serial_number_a.GetBuffer(0);
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a static variable at all?

Comment: The whole point of `static` keyword for local variables is that the variable is only initialized once, when execution first passes over its declaration. Is this not what you want? If not, just drop `static`.

Comment: static CStringA serial_number_a(serial_number); try splitting this statement into two lines. static CStringA serial_number_a; serial_number_a(serial_number);

Comment: I have decided to rewrite the code completely. I used static because i needed the variable to preserve it when leave the function. declare variable on the outside make the function obsolete.